# How to fix "Whitelabel Error Page" in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

- I have **HomeController.java** like this:

```
package controllers;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping("/home")
    public String home() {
        return "home";
    }
}
```

- I also put my html file resources/templates/home.html but when I run, I get this error on web:

> Whitelabel Error Page
> This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
>
> Wed Feb 22 21:22:21 ICT 2023
> There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
> No message available

My pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.baothien</groupId>
    <artifactId>todos</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>todoapp</name>
    <description>TodoApp Spring Web</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>19</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

- I don't know how to fix it, I'm a newbie learn Spring.
- Help me, pls. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your resource files are missing i.e. html and other stuff I think. If not then please check that you added home.html file inside src/main/resources/templates folder? if no then create home.html and put inside src/main/resources/templates if yes and still not working then add below line in src/main/resources/application.properties
**spring..resources.web.staticLocations=classpath:/static/**
add home.html like I had done
[image]